# How do I "Separate by carriage return" (javascript)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I got my extension removed and I got this message from Chrome Dev Support:

> Dear Developer,
>
> We routinely review items in the Chrome Web Store for compliance with our Program policies to ensure a safe and trusted experience for our users. Your item **** is being taken down as it currently violates the section of the Developer Program Policy relating to Malicious Products as its obfuscating a part of code. Per our policies, where possible, make as much of your code visible in the package as you can. If some of your app's logic is hidden and it appears to be suspicious, we may remove it."
>
> [Separate by carriage return]
>
> To have your item reinstated, please make any necessary changes to ensure:
>
> All of the files and code are included in the item’s package.
> All code inside the package is human readable (no obfuscated or minified code).
> Avoid requesting or executing remotely hosted code (including by referencing remote javascript files or executing code obtained by XHR requests).

I assume that "Seperate by carriage return" is a custom message from reviewer but I don't really know what carriage return even means and how do I seperate by carriage return. Please help!

Comment: I think is just a review parsing glitch. Separate by carriage return just means that the two paragraphs are separated with a return. A carriage return is a new line.

Comment: It says that your extension contains obfuscated, minified, or external javascript code.  The comment in brackets could be a formatting instruction which you can ignore.  Yet, it might also mean that your code is unreadable because it is all on a single line (no line breaks), which is typical of compressed (minified) code. Regardless, this is not really a programming question.